# Can I USB tether from my Android phone to an Android TV streaming device?

Tags: usb, tethering, android-tv

Is there any way to USB tether to/from my phone to my Android-TV box/stick/dongle without relying on WiFi?

[image: image of devices tethered together by cables]

Comment: It should work if your other device has support for "USB Ethernet", most Android devices have it. It's easy to test, why haven't you yet?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Because I haven't bought a device yet until I can confirm this works. Maybe you could test it and report back to me.